# Filter array of infinitely nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

Let's say I have an array of nested objects such as:

```
const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        children:[
            {
                id: 2,
                children:[
                    {
                        id: 3,
                        children:[
                            {
                                id: 4,
                                children: [],
                            },
                            {
                                id: 5,
                                children: [],
                            }
                        ],
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        children:[
            {
                id: 9,
                children:[
                    {
                        id: 10,
                        children:[],
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

And I would like to return a new array with id: 3 excluded for example. So it would become:

```
const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        children:[
            {
                id: 2,
                children:[],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        children:[
            {
                id: 9,
                children:[
                    {
                        id: 10,
                        children:[],
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

The excluded id can be from any level, and it and its children should be removed. What's the best approach to do this? I've tried several other solutions with no luck so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursion and `Array.reduce`,..

eg.

```js
const data=[{id:1,children:[{id:2,children:[{id:3,children:[{id:4,children:[]},{id:5,children:[]}]},]},]},{id:8,children:[{id:9,children:[{id:10,children:[]},]},]},]


function removeId(data, id) {
  return data.reduce((a,v) => {
    if (v.id !== id) 
       a.push({...v, children: removeId(v.children, id)});
    return a;
  }, []);
}

const r = removeId(data, 3);

console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` to reach each node of the object:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data, (key, value) => {
   // If children is an array and it contains an id equal to 3, we filter out that child
   if (key === 'children' && value instanceof Array) return value.filter(x=>x.id!==3);
   // Otherwise we don't intervene
   return value;
}));
```

Example:

```js
const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        children:[
            {
                id: 2,
                children:[
                    {
                        id: 3,
                        children:[
                            {
                                id: 4,
                                children: [],
                            },
                            {
                                id: 5,
                                children: [],
                            }
                        ],
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        children:[
            {
                id: 9,
                children:[
                    {
                        id: 10,
                        children:[],
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
];

console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data, (key, value) => {
   if (key === 'children' && value instanceof Array) return value.filter(x=>x.id!==3);
   return value;
})));
```

Since the two JSON methods are natively implemented by browsers, this solution is usually faster